# BackboneJS, having trouble with success and error when saving a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some reason, I cannot enter my `success` and `error` blocks when I am saving my model.  Wether my response is successful "201" or error "404", my code will not hit the `debugger` lines.  Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

```
SignInView.prototype.login = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return this.model.save(this.credentials(), {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users/sign_in'
  }, {
    success: (function(_this) {
      return function(userSession, response) {
        debugger;
        return window.location.href = "/";
      };
    })(this),
    error: (function(_this) {
      return function(userSession, response) {
        debugger;
        var message;
        message = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).error;
        return alert(message);
      };
    })(this)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` function only takes two parameters -- you are passing your success and error functions as a third param.  Try the following:

```
SignInView.prototype.login = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return this.model.save(this.credentials(), {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users/sign_in',
    success: (function(_this) {
      return function(userSession, response) {
        debugger;
        return window.location.href = "/";
      };
    })(this),
    error: (function(_this) {
      return function(userSession, response) {
        debugger;
        var message;
        message = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).error;
        return alert(message);
      };
    })(this)
  });
};
```